# obtener nombre de un id de otra tabla

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo esta tabla

```
|ID|nombre |   
|1 |Ricardo|  
|2 |Roberto|
|3 |Brayan |
```

Y luego es ta otra

```
|ID_comment|Escrito_por|dirigido a|Comentario |
|1         |2          | 1        | Comentario| 
|2         |3          | 1        | Comentario|
|3         |2          | 1        | Comentario|
|4         |4          | 1        | Comentario|
|5         |3          | 1        |           |
```

Mi problema es que no sé de qué forma puedo mostrar el nombre de quien dirige el comentario que es fk de la tabla usuarios con los demás datos. Intenté con join  o una subconsulta,

El resultado que busco es :

|ID_comment|Escrito_por|dirigido a|Comentario |nombre del quien escribio|

pero en el campo de la persona que  'escrito por'el  valor se puede repetir. a lo cual la consulta bota los primeros 4 campos correctamente pero el nombre de quien escribió bota una consulta repetida

|ID_comment|Escrito_por|dirigido a|Comentario |nombre del quien escribio|

|1|2|1|Comentario |Ricardo|

|2|2|1|Comentario |Ricardo|

|3|2|1|Comentario |Ricardo|

como se ve el comentario 2 repite el nombre de Ricardo cuando el no lo escribió. aqui esta mi select:

SELECT `nombre`, `Id_comment`, `commentario`, `dirigido a` FROM `comments` FULL JOIN `users` ON `users`.`escrito por`=2

probe con todos los joins ah agregue otra tabla pero se sigue repitiendo ese valor y no se como arreglarlo.

Comment: Hola Alfredo Raúl, deberías añadir algo más de información para completar la pregunta; por ejemplo, la base de datos que estás usando sería importante, y sería buen que también añadieses un ejemplo del resultado que buscas (dados los parámetros) y los intentos con el join y la subconsulta (junto a los resultados incorrectos que obtuviste). De ese modo podremos ver si había algún error y ayudarte a corregirlo.

Comment: Si puedes volcar el SQL de las tablas con registros y adjuntar el Diagrama Entidad-Relación, sería más sencillo ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces un JOIN tienes q poner las columnas por las q unes las tablas en la parte On en este caso unes comentarios con users por el ID del escritor y el correspondiente id en la tabla de users

SELECT nombre, Id_comment, commentario, dirigido aFROM comments FULL JOIN users ON comments.escrito por=users.id